# I want to determine active tabs by the current day in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tabs, momentjs

I have 7 tabs in my vuejs page ,my purpose is to active the tabs by the current day , so if today is Friday then specific tab should be ctive on first load , But i got stuck and can't navigate to other tabs , the active tab is activated only and not the othe tabs  after if else statements , So how should i activate the other tabs when i clicked on it not only activate it when the day is today

[image]

```html
<template>

  <div>
    <div id="tabs" class="container">
      <div class="tabs">
        <a v-on:click="timestamp = 1"
           v-bind:class="[timestamp === 1 ? 'active' : '' ]">Friday</a>
          <a
            v-on:click="timestamp = 2"
            v-bind:class="[timestamp === 2 ? 'active' : '']"
            >Thursday</a>
          <a
            v-on:click="timestamp = 3"
            v-bind:class="[timestamp === 3 ? 'active' : '']"
            >Wednesday</a>
          <a
            v-on:click="timestamp = 4"
            v-bind:class="[timestamp === 4 ? 'active' : '']"
            >Tuesday</a>
          <a
            v-on:click="timestamp = 5"
            v-bind:class="[timestamp === 5 ? 'active' : '']"
            >Monday</a>
          <a
            v-on:click="timestamp = 6"
            v-bind:class="[timestamp === 6 ? 'active' : '']"
            >Sunday</a>
          <a
            v-on:click="timestamp = 7"
            v-bind:onClick="[timestamp === 7 ? 'active' : '']"
            >Saturday</a>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
          <div v-if="timestamp === 1 " class="tabcontent">
        </div>

        <div v-if="timestamp === 2" class="tabcontent">
          Content for tab two
        </div>
        <div v-if="timestamp === 3" class="tabcontent">
          Content for tab three
        </div>
        <div v-if="timestamp === 4" class="tabcontent">
          Content for tab three
        </div>
        <div v-if="timestamp === 5" class="tabcontent">
          Content for tab three
        </div>
        <div v-if="timestamp === 6" class="tabcontent">
          Content for tab three
        </div>
        <div v-if="timestamp === 7" class="tabcontent">
          Content for tab three
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

</template>

<script>

  import moment from 'moment';

  export default {
    data: function() {

         return {
           activetab:'',
           pageName: 'MB',
           pageDescription: 'This is MB',

        data: {
        timestamp : '',
         activetab:''
       },

   }
    },
    
    
    name: 'mb',
    
    computed: {
      timestamp : function() {
        if ( moment().format('dddd') === "Saturday"){
          return 7
         } else if ( moment().format('dddd') === "Sunday") {
          return 6
        }else if ( moment().format('dddd') === "Monday") {
          return 5
        }else if ( moment().format('dddd') === "Tuesday") {
          return 4
        }else if ( moment().format('dddd') === "Wednesday") {
          return 3
        }else if ( moment().format('dddd') === "Thursday") {
         return 2
       }else if ( moment().format('dddd') === "Friday"){
         return 1

      } else (moment().format('dddd') === "hassan")
       return 2
    }
   },
  };

</script>
```

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) to show the issue happening.

Comment: You probably didn't intend this: `v-bind:onClick="[timestamp === 7 ? 'active' : '']"`

Comment: Here is the code on "codesandbox.io"  
https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-darwin-3q2zd?file=/src/App.vue
As you see it can't navigate to other tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to assign a value to a computed who has no setter.
I think the easiest way to do is to put the initial logic in a `created` hook and assign to a variable `timestamp`

(And maybe a [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) can be useful in this situation with so many `if`)

```
<script>
import moment from 'moment';
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
       activetab:'',
       pageName: 'MB',
       pageDescription: 'This is MB',
       timestamp: 1,
       data: {
         timestamp : '',
         activetab:''
       }
     }
  },
  name: 'mb',
  created() {
    if ( moment().format('dddd') === "Saturday"){
      this.timestamp = 7
    } else if ( moment().format('dddd') === "Sunday") {
      this.timestamp = 6
    } else if ( moment().format('dddd') === "Monday") {
      this.timestamp = 5
    } else if ( moment().format('dddd') === "Tuesday") {
      this.timestamp = 4
    } else if ( moment().format('dddd') === "Wednesday") {
      this.timestamp = 3
    } else if ( moment().format('dddd') === "Thursday") {
      this.timestamp = 2
    } else if ( moment().format('dddd') === "Friday"){
      this.timestamp = 1
    } else (moment().format('dddd') === "hassan")
      this.timestamp = 2
  }
}
</script>
```